# Is it safe to send prisma schema objects as requests to REST API

Tags: node.js, api, next.js, prisma

I made a simple API using `Next.js`, and wanted to allow the frontend part more customizable way to call the api. Means: the frontend decides what to include/select in the response from the server. As I am using `Prisma`, it allows the frontend to send the prisma-object parameter in the request. Then the backend just includes it inside the Prisma action and sends back the result to the frontend.

For example:

**Request**

```
Method: POST
Headers:
  Content-Type: application/json
Body:
  {
    "data": {
      "name": "Foo Bar",
      "age": 34
    },
    "include": {
      "posts": true
    }
  }
```

**Backend**

```
const { body } = req;
const user = await prisma.user.create({
  ...body
});
res.status(200).json(user);
```

My question is: taking into consideration that the api routes check for session and roles, is it safe to implement an API in this way?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the actual implementation, there shouldn't be a problem. It can especially be useful if your web application is a monorepo or a single application that includes both backend and frontend code, in which case you can use Typescript to strongly type the request using the Prisma Client.

However, you should consider whether or not this implementation follows REST API fundamentals. Having a single endpoint to create and delete resources dynamically using the request body does not follow suit with how REST APIs should be designed; with REST your endpoints should describe what resources you are creating, modifying, deleting.

Your use case is part of the reason why GraphQL exists. I highly suggest reading up on GraphQL. Prisma also has a lot of GraphQL generators that automatically generate GraphQL CRUD schemas by reading Prisma schemas. For example, @paljs/generator.